# VBScript for current selections

Tags: vbscript, qlikview

I have a requirement, where I need to identify current selections i.e. Object Name, ObjectID and Selected Values.

So, I found two different VBScripts. Please find below the 2 scripts.
Now I need your help to club both the scrips.

1. For identifying object name:

   ```
   Sub Objects()
       Shtobj = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.GetSheetObjects

       For i = LBound(Shtobj) To UBound(Shtobj)
           Obj = Shtobj(i).GetCaption.Name.v
           ObjId = Shtobj(i).GetObjectId

           MsgBox Obj
           MsgBox ObjId
       Next
   End Sub
   ```
2. For identifying selected values:

   ```
   Sub theFieldValues()
       Set myfield = ActiveDocument.Fields("Month Name").GetPossibleValues

       For i = 0 To myfield.Count - 1
           K = myfield.Item(i).Text
           MsgBox K
       Next
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: SO is not a place where we rewrite code that you found somewhere else. What have you tried to make this work? What doesn't work the way you expected? What is the desired result in the first place?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Sorry, I am not good with VBScript. I tried calling myfield = Shtobj(i).GetPossibleValues.Name.V and tried calling Object Name as variable in place of "Month Name".GetPossibleValues.But nothing is working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. You need to show a [mcve] of the code that isn't working and explain how *exactly* "nothing is working".

Comment: Half your problem is that `ActiveDocument` will refer to the current document in `word-vba`, and not `vbscript`, so you've tagged it wrongly in the first place...

Comment: @Dave No. He's using Qlikview where apparently [`ActiveDocument` is a default global variable](http://blog.infovizion.ru/2014/07/sample-of-qlikview-automation-by-external-vbscript-scripts/).